# A function such that $\{f(x)>0\}$ not measurable despite $\{f(x)=\alpha\}$ measurable for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am asked to construct a function $f$ such that $\{f(x)=\alpha\}$ is Lebesgue measurable for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ but the set $\{f(x)>0\}$ is not Lebesgue measurable.

Here is what I am thinking. First, we let $V$ be a vitali set in $I:=(0,1]$. Let $f(x)=x\chi_{_V}(x)$. This defines a function from $I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $\alpha\in V$, then $\{f(x)=\alpha\}=\{\alpha\}$ which is measurable. If $\alpha \in V^c\backslash \{0\}$ then $\{f(x)=\alpha\}=\emptyset$ which is also measurable. The only problem though is that the set $\{f(x)=0 \}=V^c$ which is not measurable. Is there some way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $f(x)=x\chi_V(x)-x\chi_{V^c}(x)$